# about Font Awesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am creating a html file where i used fontawsome icons
when i am using any brand icon like facebook, discord,etc it just shows up normally, but when i use any normal icons like magnifying tool and any other it just showing some squares and doesn't shows up the real icon i added the latest fontawsome cdn in head also.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

       <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
       <i class="fa-regular fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
       <i class="fa-duotone fa-phone"></i>
       <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>` is not a "Pro Icon" so you can use it for free.

[image: Not a Pro]

`<i class="fa-regular fa-magnifying-glass"></i>` is a "Pro Icon" so you **cannot** use it for free.

[image: Pro]